# Query of users for some age, gender, and state, using a subselect

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, sorting, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT u.id,u.email,u.verified,u.verified_on,u.created_on,ca.html AS age,cg.html AS gender,cs.html AS state
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN combo ca ON ca.combo_group='age' AND ca.value =u.age
LEFT JOIN combo cg ON cg.combo_group='gender' AND cg.value =u.gender
LEFT JOIN combo cs ON cs.combo_group='state' AND cs.value =u.state ORDER BY created_on DESC) users ORDER BY email ASC;
```

I am using sub query because I want sort `created_on DESC` and `email ASC`.

Would using sub query affect performance?

Comment: Cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/20492709/398670. Please do NOT duplicate your questions across multiple sites; if you really feel you must, link between them to avoid wasting everybody's time.

Comment: yes my friend have posted there because i was not getting response from here and i banned from asking question in SO

Comment: @user20907171 Guess why you're banned on Stack Overflow? If you copy and paste posts, you'll get banned here pretty quickly too. Consider changing whatever behavior is getting you banned instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query doesn't do what you think it does. It discards the original ordering when it re-sorts. It might, depending on the sorting algorithm chosen, happen to come out how you want, but there's no guarantee.

> I am using sub query because i want sort created_on DESC and email ASC

If that's what you want, just write:

```
ORDER BY created_on DESC, email ASC
```

Your bigger worry with performance is that `combo` side table, which appears to be [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and thus likely to be painful in performance terms. Consider using a `hstore` or `json` field instead.

Answer (score 5):

Nested query is unnecessary in this case, you can rewrite the query as,

```
SELECT 
    u.id
   ,u.email
   ,u.verified
   ,u.verified_on
   ,u.created_on
   ,ca.html AS age
   ,cg.html AS gender
   ,cs.html AS state
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN combo ca ON ca.combo_group='age' AND ca.value =u.age
    LEFT JOIN combo cg ON cg.combo_group='gender' AND cg.value =u.gender
    LEFT JOIN combo cs ON cs.combo_group='state' AND cs.value =u.state 
ORDER BY u.created_on DESC, u.email ASC
```